# Drools update() not causing refire

Tags: drools

I have the following 2 rules in my system. I am using 7.73.0.  It is being run in a stateful session.

Rule 11 will fire but Rule 10 is not fired as a result of Rule 11.  I would expect rule 11 to fire and then rule 10 because of the `update` statement.

I have debugged my code with a breakpoint on the `setValue("A")` in rule 11 and see that the method is being called and the value is set properly.

Can anyone tell me why rule 10 will not fire as a result of the `update` statement?

```
rule "MYRULES_10"
    when
        prod : Product(sku != "1")
        $txt1 : TextOption(sku == "mm", value == "A")
    then
        prod.setOptionEnabled( "to2", false, "Not available rule 10" );
end

// rule values at B11, header at B5
rule "MYRULES_11"
    when
        prod : Product(sku != "1")
        $opt1 : TextChoiceOption(sku == "mt")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("val1")) from $opt1.value)
        $txt1 : TextOption(sku == "mm")
    then
        $txt1.setValue("A"); update($txt1);
end
```

*additional info:*

If I fireAllRules on the session immediately after the initial fireAllRules, Rule 10 still will not fire.

If I take the result of the first stateful session and put all the facts into a second session and fireAllRules then rule 10 is fired and then rule 11 is fired.

If I put the fact in initially with `fact mm having value A` then rule 10 fires first and then rule 11 will fire.

Comment: can you share simplest reproducible project to reproduce the problem somewhere on github? rule 10 should be activated generally

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Stateless Session or Sequential Mode for your session? If yes, then this is the expected behaviour. https://docs.drools.org/8.31.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/rule-engine/index.html#phreak-sequential-mode-con_rule-engine

Another option is that property reactivity is now working as expected because you are using the discouraged `update()` function to let Drools know about the modification of your facts. Try to use `modify()` instead:

```
...
then
    modify($txt1){
        setValue("A")
    }
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am pretty sure I am using stateful sessions.  By default sequential mode is off according to your link.  Anyhow I set 
SequentialOption.NO
and
SequentialAgendaOption.DYNAMIC
 just in case.  But I am getting the same results.

Comment: What about using `modify`?

Comment: `modify` sets the value in rule 11 but rule 10 is never refired after the set.  I have `SequentialOption.NO` and `SequentialAgendaOption.DYNAMIC` set and I am testing in both stateful and stateless sessions with the same results.  I create a KieBase from `KieContainer` using `newKieBase` passing in my configuration .  Then I create the sessions from the KieBase.

Comment: Could you please try without setting the SequentialAgendaOption.DYNAMIC option?